# How to get the internet facing IP address of a Windows VPN client?

Tags: windows, vpn, ip-address

We have a number of users VPNing into a Windows 2012 server. Using VPN provided by Routing and Remote access on Windows server. Mostly this works fine, but I have one or two users who sometimes complain about their VPN connection dropping. Given that it is fine for others, I am fairly confident that the problem lies either at their end or somewhere on the route between us and them. They travel around as well, which doesn't help.

I would like to be able to demonstrate where the problem lies and was hoping a simple tracert might be a good starting point. So a tracert between our server and their laptop - or at least to their router. RRAS will give me their internally allocated IP address, but **is it possible to get the internet facing IP address that is being used at their end for the connection**?

I would prefer not to go the route of installing a dynamic dns client, but that would be an option. Similarly I could ask them to run tracert, but that might push their technical skills which is why I would prefer to run it from my server.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A longshot, but `netstat -aon` should yield a list of established connections which you can filter by your VPN server port or PID.

Copypaste the connected IPs into a tool like [PingInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multiple_ping_tool.html) and run ping to see if any connection is dropping packets. When you identify "problematic" IPs, you can run tracert (or, even better, [WinMTR](http://winmtr.net/download-winmtr/)) on them.

Comment: That is perfect. `netstat -aon | find "1723"` lists them all. (Don't have many). Thank you.